How to enable WIN 10/11 LAN file sharing
I wish to share files between multiple Windows 10 & 11 PC's on a home network.
The LAN uses a mix of wired ethernet and Wifi.
My preference would be to allow complete hard drive access on any PC from any PC. I'm aware that that is considered somewhat hazardous. More restricted sharing of selected folders could be acceptable.
Long ago in the days of workgroups and home groups I managed this with relative ease.
I have looked at numerous online guides as to how to achieve this, noted that many people have problems, and so far not been able to do what I want.
I have followed instructions re "advanced network sharing", enabled file and printe sharing on local networks but not public networks, enabled media sharing, turned OFF password sharing, enaabled 128 bit encryption. Enabled auto starting of 4 services as recommended in reference 1 below, and torn my hair out.
Any advice is welcome.
Accessing drive on same PC dir \OwnPCName\OwnHDDName
On a PC named "THEWIND" running Windows 11 version 23H2, with hard drive C: named C the "DOS prompt" command "dir \THEWIND\C" produces a directory of C:\ as expected and eg "dir \THEWIND\C\BAT" also works as expected.
On two other WIN10 PCs with HDD C: named C an equivalent attempt eg "dir \ThisPCNameC" produces "The network path was not found".
Accessing drive on another PC using dir \OtherPCName\OtherHDDName
All attempts too access HDDs on other PCs fail.
If the PC name exists the message is "The network path was not found.
If the PC name does not exists the message is "The network name cannot be found".
ie the far PC is seen if it exists, but the HDD name is not recognised.
Enabling file sharing
Selecting a folder and enabling files sharing for "Everyone" does not allow access.
References
This is old but seems to cover the same or more than newer material.
Microsoft community Homegroup removed! How to get network sharing work with Windows 10 v1803.
I could provide a number of other links to advice that also doesn't seem to work, but ... .
